# Relation between potential good reduction of curves and belyi maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth proper curve over a number field $K$, and let $f : X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1_K$ a degree $n$ map unramified outside $\{0,1,\infty\}$.

I've read in various places that something of the following type is true:

$$\text{$X$ has potential good reduction at all primes $p > n$.}$$

Does anyone have a reference for this?

EDIT: Thanks to Vesselin Dimitrov, this is implied by $\S4,5$ of Beckman's "Ramified Primes in the Field of Moduli of Branched Coverings".

Secondly, is the following known to be true?
$$\text{$X$ has potential good reduction at all places away from 2,3, and the primes dividing $n$}$$

Thirdly, could something of the following type be true?
$$\text{There exists a finite set $S$ of primes, independent of $X,f$, such that $X$ has potential good}$$
$$\text{reduction at all primes $p\notin S$ which do not divide the ramification indices of $f$}$$
(Ie, does anyone know of a counterexample to such a statement?)
In particular I'd be interested in seeing a counterexample in the cases where $S = \emptyset$ and $S = \{2,3\}$.

Note that in both cases I'm asking only about good reduction of $X$, not good reduction of $f$.

Comment: The more precise condition is that $p$ does not divide the order of the Galois group (which in turn divides $n!$). Did any of the places that gave this statement make a reference to the paper [*Ramified primes in the field of moduli of branched coverings of curves*, J. Algebra, 1989] by Sybilla Beckmann? It should be possible to read this from *Corollary 5.7* at the very end of her paper.

Comment: (And you actually need the strict inequality $p > n$ in your first display.)

Comment: (Sorry, this is Proposition 5.3, not 5.7, of that paper. Also, by 'Galois group' here I mean the group of the Galois closure of the covering. That means your more precise condition in the first display is indeed right in the case of a Galois covering.)